# pass ajax data to django model with many to many relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, react-fullstack

I've been working on this for a while and Im stumped.  I've been reading through the docs...

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

and still cant make sense of how this is supposed to work.

If someone could help me solve this error or explain how this is supposed to work I would be very happy to get some help.  Thanks

What I want:

1. send ajax to django rest framework api endpoint
2. have django / DRF save many-to-many related data in postgreSQL db

What I've got:

TypeError: Session() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pose_list'

**models.py**

```
class Pose(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class SeshPoseList(models.Model):
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    pose_fk = models.ForeignKey(Pose, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Session(models.Model):
    session_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

***serializers.py***

```
class PoseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Pose
        fields = ('id', 'name')

class SeshPoseListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Session.objects.create(**validated_data)

    class Meta:
        model = SeshPoseList
        fields = ['order', 'pose_fk']

class SessionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pose_list = SeshPoseListSerializer(many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Session.objects.create(**validated_data)

    class Meta:
        model = Session
        fields = ('id', 'session_name', 'pose_list')
```

***views.py***

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def session_list(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        seshSerializer = SessionSerializer(data=request.data)
        if seshSerializer.is_valid():
            seshSerializer.create(seshSerializer.validated_data)
            return Response(seshSerializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        print("sesh errors --->  ", seshSerializer.errors)
        return Response(seshSerializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```